# What is the difference in functionality between Azure Durable entities and NoSQL databases?

Tags: azure-functions, nosql, azure-durable-functions

I am new to Azure Functions and Durable Entities. It seems like Durable Entities allow Durable functions to track state. How is this different from what other NoSQL database provides apart from first-class integration with the Azure ecosystem?

Answer (score 0):

Durable entities are not just about tracking or storing state. Each entity can be assumed to logically represent a unit of work or service in a concurrent environment. They are based on the [Actor model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model) of concurrency which implements message-passing semantics.

> An actor is a computational entity that, in response to a message it
> receives, can concurrently:
>
> - send a finite number of messages to other actors
> - create a finite number of new actors
> - designate the behavior to be used for the next message it receives

In a nutshell, they represent a concurrency facility in Azure function runtime that allows you to easily implement many [concurrent asynchronous application patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=csharp#application-patterns) in a serverless environment.